# get element position in terms of their class javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
<div>
  <input class='input' onChange={ func } />
  <input class='input' onChange={ func } />
  <input class='input' onChange={ func } />
</div>
```

I have this function

```js
const func = (event) => {
  ...
}
```

how do I get the index of the submitted element? like i want to get the position of the submitted element in terms of their class

Comment: If u don't know what I'm talking about , basically I want it to tell me what the position of the submitted element is in the class array

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Maybe adding a data attribute to each input would help.

Comment: You can add a parameter like this. onChange={(e) => func(e, 1)}

Comment: I'm sorry still not clear, what is your problem exactly?  what do you mean by `"class array"`?

Comment: What class array? Do you mean server side or in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Your `onChange={ func }` looks weird to me. I think it should be `onChange="func(event)"`.

---

You could solve this with `indexOf()` and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`) in Javascript:

```js
const func = (event) => {
  console.log([...event.target.parentNode.children].indexOf(event.target));
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class='input' onChange="func(event)" />
  <input class='input' onChange="func(event)" />
  <input class='input' onChange="func(event)" />
</div>
```

or with `index()` in jQuery:

```js
const func = (event) => {
  console.log($(event.target).index());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class='input' onChange="func(event)" />
  <input class='input' onChange="func(event)" />
  <input class='input' onChange="func(event)" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll('#stack input');

const run = () => {
    for (const inputElement of inputElements) {
        inputElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            const index = [...inputElements].findIndex(input => input === this)
            console.log(index)
        })
    }
}

run();


<div id='stack'>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

changed your usecase alittle bit. you can easly implement it to your code